# Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop - Remote desktop not working at all times

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop

I have a second computer running Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop (it serves as a mini server to test), on which I have the screen sharing option enabled via RDP to easily access via the main computer. For some unknown reason, up to an hour after disconnecting from RDP, it is not possible to reconnect to RDP.
I have to deliberately rewire the keyboard and mouse to disable and re-enable the RDP screen sharing option so that I can connect. Is there a possible solution to this problem?